# What does this SQL statement do?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to understand this SQL statements :

```
$id = 5;

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');

    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Can someone please explain me step by step what exactly is going on here?

From what i understand :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
```

**1)** *$stmt is about to take as iinput an SQL query. The SQL query is to select all the rows from a table that their id is equal to 5.*

```
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
```

**2)** *We execute the statement. Now the $stmt has these rows?*

```
$row = $stmt->fetch()
```

**3)** *This is the most confusing line for me. What exactly happens here? Variable "row" takes one by one the rows that have id = 5 ? Is that what fetch() does ? And if yes , how exaxtly does it return the results? Its an array of all the correct answers? EG all the rows that have id = 5 ? I dont understand how exactly this while loop works here.The first time it runs "row" will have the first row ? The second time it runs , will have the second row that satisfies our creteria (id = 5) and so on? Is it like that every time i run fetch one result will be returned? And next time i run fetch , the next result , till there is no more result to satisfy the query?*

I thing i am so close to get this one. Anything that could help me understand it completely would be highly appreciated !

Comment: It seems you confusion is with the PHP code rather than the SQL

Comment: Google "prepared statements" and the PHP manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain as comments:

```
$id = 5;

// Create a prepared statement - don't actually execute the statement yet. 
// The :id value in the statement will be replaced by a parameter value (safely) when the
// statement is executed
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');

// Execute the statement against the DB - the $stmt var now contains the result set for the
// executed statement. e.g. it contains *all* the results that the query fetched
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

// Now we loop through the rows in the result set (they are all in memory at this point). 
// "fetch" will start from row 1 and return the next result each time you call it again. 
// when there are no more rows it returns FALSE and therefore breaks out of the while loop
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Just checking docs also and whilst this is how it was done previously (been years since I've touched PHP) it looks like `stmt->fetch()` actually places results into bound variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

```
$row = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);

// loop through all result rows
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Does the code you originally posted actually work? It doesn't appear you bind any variables and therefore since the `$stmt-fetch()` call returns bool TRUE/FALSE it would seem to be that `$row` would not get set to anything but TRUE/FALSE

Comment: Just a note on your last comment: `fetch()` doesn't return nothing (implying null) at the end. It returns `FALSE` which is what causes the while loop to break out.

Comment: No idea, I don't use PHP :D

Answer (score 2):

here it uses PDO for execution,

Repeated SELECT using prepared statements through which you can call repeated query

`$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');`

it defines the prepared statement where `:id` is placeholder

`$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));`

this places assigns the value to placeholder and execute the query

`$row = $stmt->fetch()`

it fetch the record from select

for more reference visit the link 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php